# wm6.5 emulator can not connect web services on the host machine

Tags: c#, emulation, windows-mobile-6.5

my windows mobile 6.5 emulator cant connect web services on the host machine. i cant solve this. the real device (motorola mc75) connected via usb cable, it is establishing connection and it can access web services on the host machine. but emulator cant. but -interesting- this emulator connect another machines (on the same network) web services. this getting me crazy.

this situation appeared i install vs2013 and windows8.1 previously I can. iss express came with vs2013. problems that may be caused. some body help.

Comment: thnx for answer. I am already doing exactly as you say. vs2012-vs2008 no problem. vs2013-vs2008 problem cause. emulator docked and connected, wmdc is green and i connect google but i cant connect http://172.20.80.89:59753/webservices/asnmobileservice.asmx   (this is my ip and my firewall is disabled). but another docked emulator on the another pc on the same network can connect my services at the http://172.20.80.89:59753/....  what is this? as i said, i was working at windows8, vs2012, vs2008. but i cant work at windows8.1, vs2013, vs2008.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator can connect to your network either via USB or a network card (this will only work with some virtual network driver).

You need to dock the emulator (can be done via the stand-alone device emulator manager). Normally the emulator device is only connected via DMA. This type of connection does support Visual Studio Debugging etc but not a PASSTHRU connection via USB.

After the emulated device is docked, Windows Mobile Device Center (WMDC) should come up. In WMDC Connection Settings you can switch the network conection for "This computer is connected to:". Choose "The Internet" there and enable "Allow data connections while connected".

If your PC is connected to the Internet without a proxy, you can test the connection inside the emulated device using the Mobile Internet Explorer and trying to open any valid home page. If that works, you should also be able to consume a web service of your PC. You can test that by entering the Web Service address inside Internet Explorer Mobile.

If you have still problems post some screen shots of WMDC connection settings of the connected emulator device.

Comment: thnx for answer. I am already doing exactly as you say. vs2012-vs2008 no problem. vs2013-vs2008 problem cause. emulator docked and connected, wmdc is green and i connect google but i cant connect 172.20.80.89:59753/webservices/asnmobileservice.asmx (this is my ip and my firewall is disabled). but another docked emulator on the another pc on the same network can connect my services at the 172.20.80.89:59753.... what is this? as i said, i was working at windows8, vs2012, vs2008. but i cant work at windows8.1, vs2013, vs2008. –  mustafatorun 17 hours ago